Cleanup testcontainers Postgres container after test-suite completion
I'm attempting to write an implementation for re-using a Postgres Testcontainer for a series of tests written in Rust.
The struct is defined as follows:
use sea_orm::{ConnectOptions, DatabaseConnection, SqlxPostgresConnector};
use std::process::Command;
use testcontainers::runners::AsyncRunner;
use testcontainers::ContainerAsync;
use testcontainers_modules::postgres::Postgres;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use uuid::Uuid;

const USER_NAME: &'static str = "<USERNAME>";
const PASSWORD: &'static str = "<PASSWORD>";

pub struct PostgresTestContainer {
    ctn: ContainerAsync<Postgres>,
}

impl PostgresTestContainer {
    pub async fn create() -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
        // Create the postgres container and return
        let ctn = Postgres::default()
            .with_user(USER_NAME)
            .with_password(PASSWORD)
            .start()
            .await?;

        Ok(Self { ctn })
    }
    pub async fn new_db(&self) -> anyhow::Result<DatabaseConnection> {
        // Expose and provide a port to localhost
        let host_port = self.ctn.get_host_port_ipv4(5432).await?;

        let db_name = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();
        // Create the database url using the host port
        let db_url = format!("postgres://{USER_NAME}:{PASSWORD}@localhost:{host_port}/{db_name}");

        let db = SqlxPostgresConnector::connect(ConnectOptions::new(&db_url)).await?;
        Ok(db)
    }
}

The current test implementation uses lazy_static to create the container and provide it for all tests:
lazy_static! {
    static ref CTN: AsyncOnce<PostgresTestContainer> =
            AsyncOnce::new(async { PostgresTestContainer::create().await.expect("Could not create postgres container" });
    ...
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn login_with_correct_pwd_returns_tokens() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
    let db = CTN.get().await.new_db().await?; 
    ...
}

This works great, except I'm struggling to determine how I can stop the container after completion. How could I write a cleanup method, or how can re-write the implementation to consider cleanup of the container after use?
I attempted to use impl Drop for PostgresTestContainer to stop the container, but after no success and a fair deal of research I learned that static objects don't call drop.
Thanks!

I think you need #![custom_test_frameworks] or otherwise writing your own test harness / using a third party one.

I looked at the cafce25's recommendation, and while #[custom_test_frameworks] looks promising, I didn't want to work with unstable rust.
I decided to use a solution I saw in this post.
First, I added a parameter to the testcontainer creation method:
pub async fn create(ctn_name: Uuid) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
    // Create the postgres container and return
    let ctn = Postgres::default()
        .with_user(USER_NAME)
        .with_password(PASSWORD)
        .with_container_name(ctn_name)
        .start().await?;

    Ok(Self { ctn })
}

Then, I created a helper method:
pub fn stop_active_container(name: &str) {
    Command::new("docker")
        .arg("rm")
        .arg("-f")
        .arg(&name)
        .status()
        .unwrap();
}

Then I used those two methods combined, along with the ctor crate, to handle creation and destruction.
lazy_static! {
    static ref CTN_ID: Uuid = Uuid::new_v4();
    static ref CTN: AsyncOnce<PostgresTestContainer> = AsyncOnce::new(async { PostgresTestContainer::create(CTN_ID.clone()).await.unwrap() });
    ...
}
...
#[dtor]
fn cleanup() {
    docker_helpers::stop_active_container(CTN_ID.clone());
}

I really don't love this solution, since it relies on calling Docker from the command line, but it seems like it'll work okay.
It'll be great to see rust develop its testing harness in the future. Having setup and teardown methods would be a fantastic addition!
